# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. in capacitor android

Tags: java, android, gradle, capacitor

i had this error while i'm building my capacitor project i tried by updating sdk but is not working, how can i fix this ?

```
google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't 
work
WARNING:: Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
Currently detected usages:
- repository flatDir used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'
WARNING:: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and 
migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
Currently detected usages in: root project 'android', project ':app', project ':capacitor- 
android', ...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment 
variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file 
at 'C:\Users\giova\Desktop\testapp\android\local.properties'.[capacitor]  

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

Comment: Do you have google-services.json in ypur app folder ? Is the SDK location correct?

Comment: I don`t have google-services.json in my app folder and how can i know what is the sdk correct location ?

Comment: The solution is in the error itself, `SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment `

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple, i had to select the project folder properly, anyways thanks for the help.